# insert url parameter in mysql with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, frameworks, codeigniter-3

I need your help!

I am new to codeigniter and I am trying to pass a fetch parameter from url, get me the value using the following

My example url is the following: http://localhost/infocargacasosfinal/index.php/creacionacta/?NroGestion=1&NroContacto=103386816

Where what I am rescuing is the value "NroContacto", I have managed to bring me the value with the following line in the controller:

```
'NroContacto' => $this->input->get('NroContacto');
```

and show it in the view with the following:

```
                        <td>
                                          Numero Folio:   <?php echo $nrocontacto; ?> 
                    </td>
```

that way I have managed to show it in the user's view, but now I can't find a way to save that value in the database when the user clicks the "save" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared much information related to your issue. I am assuming that you need two server calls to save the URL parameter into data.

1. First "http://localhost/infocargacasosfinal/index.php/creacionacta/?NroGestion=1&NroContacto=103386816", is used to render the page with a form to submit.
2. Second, When the user clicks the submit button in the form, data is stored in a database.

If this is the case, on first page, you can collect **nrocontacto** as you have already done in your code and add a hidden input field `<input type="hidden" name="nrocontacto" value="<?php echo $nrocontacto; ?>">` inside the form in the view file.

When the user submit the form, you can grab the value using `$nroContacto = $this->input->post('NroContacto', true);` (*this code goes to form processing controller method*). Now you can use CI query builder `$this->db->insert('tableName', array('field_name' => $nroContacto));` (*Note: add other required fields for insert array*) to save it to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter support seo friendly urls so you can arrange your url like this
http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up

for your url it will be

```
http://localhost/infocargacasosfinal/index.php/creacionacta/1/103386816
```

Now you can fetch like this

```
'NroContacto' => $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
```

now pass the value to your view page.

You can get detailed documentation about url segments here

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html